# Did any customers lose money with the Mt Gox / Dwolla legal situation?

Tags: mtgox, dwolla

This crucial piece of info has been frustratingly absent from the news accounts I've seen. Specifically from what I understand, an account was "frozen".  What does that mean for the people unlucky enough to have had their transaction present in the account at the time of "freezing"?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the timeline for my deposit, which shows that at least one deposit was honored:

1. May 14 @ 10:14 AM CST --> Dwolla notified me that money was sent
2. May 14 @ 12:16 PM CST --> Dwolla notified me that DHS seized Mt Gox's account
3. May 14 @ 08:53 PM CST --> Mt. Gox notified me that funds from dwolla were deposited

I can't speak about other transactions with certainty, but from the fact that my deposit went through and the lack of any major "I lost $3,700 during the DHS crackdown" news stories, my guess is that all transactions that happened around this time were either honored or rolled back.